# How to create a 3D vector using XYZ angles

Tags: math, vector, lua, trigonometry

So i found out how to create a vector2 in 2D using only one angle but now i need a vector3 using two or three angles

The code i used to get the 2D vector:

```
function V2ToForce(Angle,Force)
    local Force = Force or 1
    local X,Y = math.cos(Angle)*Force,math.sin(Angle)*Force 
    return X,Y
end
```

Any pseudocode would help.

**Edit:**
I found this formula but dosent work either

```
function Test(X,Y,Force)    
    local x = math.cos(X) * math.cos(Y);    
    local z = math.sin(X) * math.cos(Y);    
    local y = math.sin(Y);  
    return x*Force,y*Force,z*Force 
end
```

Comment: `dosent work` - Why do you think so?  Do you have example of input and correct output for checking whether your calculation is correct?

Comment: If all the angles are 0, what should the vector be? (1,0,0)? All you'd have to do is rotate that vector around each axis. The order is up to you. (also note if you rotated that vector around the x axis first it'd have no effect) Also you only need two angles to produce any 3d vector. You could rotate it around the Y axis first, then the X. (like how you look around in an fps) (hence why that formula only takes x and y)

Comment: if all angles are 0 it could be from 0 to 1 in any cordinate

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff i tested it in Lua when X is from 0 to 360 (in radians) it works but when the Y changes the Vector3 Y always is     -1 to 5 and not 0-1 btw the force isnt the problem

Comment: You really should put a proper code in the question which would show what's wrong. The formulas you've edited in are well known, and I highly doubt that `math.sin` would return something wrong on a normal input.

Comment: @Dimitry There is the code
 `function Test(X,Y,Force)
 local x = math.cos(X) * math.cos(Y);
 local z = math.sin(X) * math.cos(Y);
 local y = math.sin(Y);
 return x*Force,y*Force,z*Force
end

for _=1,360 do
 Test(math.rad(_),math.rad(_),1)
end`

Comment: Everything works for me: `function verify(...) for _,x in ipairs({...}) do assert( (-1<=x) and (x<=1)) end end` `for i = -1000,1000 do for j = -1111,1111 do verify(Test(i,j,1)) end end print('No fails')`

Comment: I tested your rotation formula and the "X,Y" angles are actually "Y,Z" angles. It begins at the x axis, rotates around Z axis first, then the Y axis. Here's the testing: `(Y=0,Z=0) returns (1,0,0)` (begins at x axis). `(Y=0,Z=90) returns (0,1,0)` (around Z = x to y). `(Y=90,Z=90) returns (0,1,0)` also. (Y around Y has no effect) And just `(Y=90,Z=0) returns (0,0,1)`. (around Y = x to z)

Comment: If you wanted the x axis (1,0,0) rotated by Y then X, use this formula instead. `x,y,z = cos(Y), sin(Y)*sin(X), -sin(Y)*cos(X)`

Answer (score 0):

Ty who commented got it to work, still has some bugs but nothing that a if statement can't solve.

Thats what i ended up with for anyone with the same problem

```
function Test1(X,Y,Force)
    local X1 = math.cos(Y)*Force
    local Y1 = (math.sin(Y)*math.sin(X))*Force
    local Z1 = (-math.sin(Y)*math.cos(X))*Force
    return X1,Y1,Z1
end
function Test2(X,Y,Force)
    local X1 = math.cos(X) * math.cos(Y)
    local Z1 = -math.sin(X) * math.cos(Y)
    local Y1 = math.sin(Y)
    return X*Force,Y*Force,Z1*Force 
end
```

Sry for my bad english